# serializeUser and deserializeUser not called; req.user always empty in PassportJS Express app

Tags: passport.js, withings

So I have a small app based on the generator-angular-fullstack. I want to add to the current logged user the credential for a new account (Withings).
The idea is that a user that is logged in can also add other way to make the login by using Withings or Twitter or Facebook.

Those are my route:

```
router
.get('/', passport.authorize('withings', { 
    failureRedirect: '/'
}))

.get('/callback', passport.authorize('withings', {
    successRedirect : '/settings',
    failureRedirect : '/'
}));
```

and this the callbacks implementation :

```
passport.use(new WithingsStrategy({
    consumerKey: config.withings.clientID,
    consumerSecret: config.withings.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.withings.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

    console.log('user' + req.user);

    return done(null, null);

  }
));
```

The point is that when I get back to the function, even if I was logged the `req.user` is always `undefined`.

Does anyone have an idea? I read that you need a couple of function like `deserializeUser` and `serializeUser` but they are never called.

Ideas? I'm new on this kind of things and after 3-4 night is getting frustrated :(

PS: this is my configuration

```
  app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(methodOverride());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session()); //persistent login session




  // Persist sessions with mongoStore
  // We need to enable sessions for passport twitter because its an oauth 1.0 strategy
  app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new mongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection })
  }));

  if ('production' === env) {
    app.use(favicon(path.join(config.root, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));
    app.set('appPath', config.root + '/public');
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
  }

  if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
    app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));
    app.set('appPath', 'client');
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(errorHandler()); // Error handler - has to be last
  }
```

Comment: [passport's express-middlewares](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) in the right places? (before router)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but in case anyone else comes past it, I see 2 problems.

First, in your callback implementation you say:

```
return done(null, null);
```

The API for `done` is `done([err], [user])`. Your code, by passing `null` as the second argument to done, is saying you didn't find a user, thus passport is not logging a user in. You actually need to say:

```
return done(null, profile);
```

Second, you need to move these lines:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

down below your `app.use(session({...}))` call. Passport depends on the express session, so you need to setup the express session before initializing passport.

Hope this helps!